# jQuery Selectable Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, selectable

I have a jQuery plugin that drags and drops elements into different containers, I want to attach some events, for example when an element is over a container. These events used to work perfectly but then they stopped working. for Some reason the Selectable specific events are not fired, but when i bind a click for example it works.

Example:

```
 //these are not working
$('#sortable2').bind("sortover", function(event, ui) {
    alert("here");
});
$('#sortable2').bind('sortreceive', function() {
      alert('User clicked on "sortable2."');
    });
$('.droptrue').bind("sortout", function(event, ui) {
    $(this).css("background", "transparent");
});
```

The related code is:

```
  var selectedClass = 'ui-state-highlight',
    clickDelay = 300,     // click time (milliseconds)
    lastClick, diffClick; // timestamps

$("ul.droptrue li")
    // Script to deferentiate a click from a mousedown for drag event
    .bind('mousedown mouseup', function(e){
        if (e.type=="mousedown") {
            lastClick = e.timeStamp; // get mousedown time
        } else {
            diffClick = e.timeStamp - lastClick;
            if ( diffClick < clickDelay ) {
                // add selected class to group draggable objects
                $(this).toggleClass(selectedClass);
            }
        }
    })
    .draggable({
        revertDuration: 10, // grouped items animate separately, so leave this number low
        containment: '.multiSelect',
        start: function(e, ui) {
            ui.helper.addClass(selectedClass);
        },
        stop: function(e, ui) {
            // reset group positions
            $('.' + selectedClass).css({ top:0, left:0 });
        },
        drag: function(e, ui) {
            // set selected group position to main dragged object
            // this works because the position is relative to the starting position
            $('.' + selectedClass).css({
                top : ui.position.top,
                left: ui.position.left
            });
        }
    });
$("ul.droptrue")
    .sortable()
    .droppable({
        drop: function(e, ui) {
            $('.' + selectedClass)
             .appendTo($(this))
             .add(ui.draggable) // ui.draggable is appended by the script, so add it after
             .removeClass(selectedClass)
             .css({ top:0, left:0 });
        }
    });

$('#total').text(autoCompleteSourceArray.length);
$('#filter-count').text(autoCompleteSourceArray.length);
//Adding Filtering functionality for the lists
$("#filter").keyup(function () {
    var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;
    $("ul.droptrue:first li").each(function () {
        if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
            $(this).addClass("hidden");
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("hidden");
            count++;
        }
    });
    $("#filter-count").text(count);
});

// bind events in order to show or hide the message in the drop zones
$('ul[id^="sortable"]').live("sortover", function(event, ui) {
    $(this).css("background", "#f7f6d7");
});
$('ul[id^="sortable"]').live("sortout", function(event, ui) {
    $(this).css("background", "transparent");
});
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: do you get any erros? or just simply not working..., if they don't work it's coz they have not been attached, or a later event unbinding, may have caused it to not work. try and paste that code on your `console` window see if it works then,

Comment: i dont get any errors, even when running from console everything is fine but the events are not bound, when i debug i have found that the inner body is not executed for some reason

Comment: "inner body" you mean the alerts? if so then it makes sense because they are not bound, so why would they :), can you use jsfiddle? to show more code, or how this works, coz it could take a while here... but, I think, you should really use the live() function coz they are dynamic and ever changing I would of thought.

Comment: thanks a lot for your concern, i have pasted the related code above, am afraid JSfiddle wont work because this is an extension for google refine thus it is not standalone .. i have tried live as you notice and it is not working .. the problem is that they used to !! then suddenly they just decided to stop !!

Comment: I can't tell much from this, I don't see anything wrong with it, perhaps you could point out what did you do that made it stop working,?

Comment: the funny part is that i did revert back the changes and nothing is affected!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5691/discussion-between-val-and-ahmadassaf)

Answer (score -1):

If you have recently updated to jQuery 1.7+ you should notice that the `live()` method is deprecated.

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use
>   .delegate() in preference to .live().